# Unable to call logged_in? method to view to change layout links

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Self explanatory title. I have a sessions_helper.rb file which has method logged_in? to check if the user is logged in but when I try to use an if statement to change links in the view file it does not work.

Code:

sessions_helper

```
module SessionsHelper
  #logs in user
  def log_in(user)
    session[:user_id] = user.id
  end

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: session[:user_id])
  end

  def logged_in?
    :current_user.nil?
  end
end
```

sessions_controller

```
def create
  user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)

  if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
    # log user in
    log_in user
    redirect_to user
```

view file

```
<% if logged_in? %> 
  # show new layout links with logout option
<% else %> 
  # show pre-login layout links
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an error in your `logged_in?` method, just change the `:` to `!` (i assume you were looking to negate `current_user`):

```
def logged_in?
  !current_user.nil?
end
```

Using `:` creates a symbol (i.e. `:current_user`) which will always return `false`, so your method `logged_in` will do too.

You are successfully calling `logged_in?` method, but its returning `false` every time, so your are getting `# show pre-login layout links` in your view as a result.

Comment: Thank you. Also I've realized from the posts here that "calling" a method from the helper isn't correct terminology, may I know what is?

Comment: @Solias "Calling" is ok, i just meant to emphasize the term to make it clear. But i see i just added confusion to it.